# ¿Cómo manejo acentos, Ñ y demás en Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, utf-8, codificación

Tengo un método que me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error (el problema es en los acentos)

> urlopen error [Errno 10061] No se puede establecer una conexi¾n ya que el equipo de destino deneg¾ expresamente dicha conexi¾n

Al intentar hacer json.dumps en python me encuentro con el error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte .....
```

Se que no es error de json porque marca lo mismo al llamar el método print, pero no he logrado

He intentado:

```
import sys
reload(sys)

sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")


variable.encode("utf8")
```

¿Como puedo hacer para obtener la cadena con los acentos y poder utilizar `json.dumps()`?

Comment: Es algo viejo, pero te recomiendo leer la siguiente presentación: https://downloads.egenix.com/python/LSM2005-Developing-Unicode-aware-applications-in-Python.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despues de leer [mucho](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) sobre [unicode](http://acdha.github.io/djangocon-internationalization-tutorial/handling-unicode.html) y django me doy cuenta de que:

1. El primer string lo tengo que cambiar a unicode, lo cual lo hago con el siguiente código:

   ```
   def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding="latin1"):
       if isinstance(obj, basestring):
           if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
               obj=unicode(obj, encoding)
       return obj
   ```

   Con esto lo tengo en unicode con el conjunto de caracteres latin1
2. Como yo lo que quiero es una respuesta json en django en json.dumps le paso el parámetro ensure_ascii=False, y posterior ejecuto el encode

   ```
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("latin1"), content_type="application/json") #HttpResponse es propio de django
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Si puedes pasarte a Python 3.x, la codificación estándar es utf-8 y todas las cadenas de texto son unicode por defecto, así que no tendrías ese problema.

En python 2.x la codificación estándar es ascii, lo que significa que te dará errores con acentos, eñes, etc... Puedes cambiar la codificación por defecto a la que tú quieras, incluyendo el siguiente código (Suponiendo que quieres utf-8):

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

En un fichero que este en el *path* de búsqueda de Python y que se tiene que llamar, obligatoriamente, `sitecustomize.py`. Este fichero puede que ya esté creado, o no, dependiendo de tu distribución y circunstancias, así que busca primero en tu sistema y crealo/editalo según corresponda.