# Ordenar una lista alfabéticamente en español incluido la Ñ y tildes

Tags: python, ordenamiento, caracteres

Estoy necesitando ayuda para resolver esto debido a que no sé como ordenar las palabras con letras Ñ y tildes. No se pueden utilizar funciones

[image: esta es la lista y como debería quedar]

```
PALABRA = ["retorno", "peñón", "ñandú", "casa",
           "zanahoria", "volar", "caña", "perezoso",
           "ñanduti", "manía", "retoño", "avispa",
           "volátil", "peña", "nadie", "oeste"]
PALABRAO = ["retorno", u"peñón", u"ñandú", "casa",
            "zanahoria", "volar", u"caña", "perezoso",
            u"ñanduti", "manía", u"retoño", "avispa",
            "volátil", u"peña", "nadie", "oeste"]
abc = []
for z in range(len(PALABRAO)):
    if "ñ" in PALABRAO[z]:
        abc.append(PALABRAO[z])
for k in range(len(PALABRA)):
    for i in range(len(PALABRA)):
        if PALABRAO[k] < PALABRAO[i]:
            PALABRAO[i], PALABRAO[k] = PALABRAO[k], PALABRAO[i]
print("Lista desordenada:\tLista Ordenada:")
for k in range(len(PALABRA)):
    print(f"{PALABRA[k]:<20}\t{PALABRAO[k]:<20}")
```

Comment: Creo que esto te puede servir [¿Cómo manejo acentos, Ñ y demás en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2391/c%C3%B3mo-manejo-acentos-%C3%91-y-dem%C3%A1s-en-python)

Comment: Puedes usar `palabra.sort()`

Comment: Esperas un ordenamiento de la letra especificada y de partir de ese punto en adelante ordenarlas alfabéticamente o un orden predeterminado que determine una cantidad numerica?

Comment: por favor evita compartir imágenes de ejemplo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supongo que el tema va de realizar un algoritmo propio.

**1.- Paso previo**

Lo primero es asegurarnos que el archivo `nombre.py` tenga la codificación correcta, una forma simple es abrirlo con el bloc de notas y guardalo con `UTF-8`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.- Crear un diccionario de valores**

```py
diccionario = {
    "a" : 0,
    u"á" : 0,
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : 2,
 #etc
}
```

La idea es asignar a cada letra un valor, dicho valor puede estar repetido, por ejemplo podemos decir que `a` y `á` tiene igual valor

De esta manera tienes pleno control en el orden que quieras dar, por ejemplo que `n > ñ > o`

**3.- Una función para comparar palabras**

```
def esMayor(p1,p2,i=0):

    if(len(p1)<=i or len(p2)<=i ):
        return len(p1)>len(p2)
    elif diccionario[p1[i]] == diccionario[p2[i]] :
        return esMayor(p1,p2,i+1)
    else:
        return diccionario[p1[i]] > diccionario[p2[i]]
```

`esMayor` retorna `true` si la palabra `p1` es mayor que `p2`. Para comparar, vamos tomando la primera letra de izquierda a derecha y comparando según su valor en el diccionario

**4.- Ordenamiento**

Como el fondo de la pregunta no es de "ordenamiento", yo tomaré cualquier algoritmo, como por ejemplo el de la [burbuja](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-bubble-sort/), tu puedes usar cualquiera, lo unico que hay que hacer es buscar donde se realiza la comparación y cambiarlo por la función `esMayor`

**Código de ejemplo**

```js
diccionario = {
    "a" : 0,
    u"á" : 0,
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : 2,
    "d" : 3,
    "e" : 4,
    u"é" : 4,
    "f" : 5,
    "g" : 5,
    "h" : 7,
    "i" : 8,
    u"í" : 8,
    "k" : 9,
    "k" : 10,
    "l" : 11,
    "m" : 12,
    "n" : 13,
    u"ñ" : 14,
    "o" : 15,
    u"ó" : 15,
    "p" : 16,
    "q" : 17,
    "r" : 18,
    "s" : 19,
    "t" : 20,
    "u" : 21,
    u"ú" : 21,
    "v" : 22,
    "w" : 23,
    "x" : 24,
    "y" : 25,
    "z" : 26
}

PALABRA = ["retorno", "peñón", "ñandú", "casa",
           "zanahoria", "volar", "caña", "perezoso",
           "ñanduti", "manía", "retoño", "avispa",
           "volátil", "peña", "nadie", "oeste", "oesteaa"]

def esMayor(p1,p2,i=0):

    if(len(p1)<=i or len(p2)<=i ):
        return len(p1)>len(p2)
    elif diccionario[p1[i]] == diccionario[p2[i]] :
        return esMayor(p1,p2,i+1)
    else:
        return diccionario[p1[i]] > diccionario[p2[i]]
       

def bubblesort(elements):
    swapped = False
    # Looping from size of array from last index[-1] to index [0]
    for n in range(len(elements)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(n):
            if esMayor(elements[i], elements[i + 1]):
                swapped = True
                # swapping data if the element is less than next element in the array
                elements[i], elements[i + 1] = elements[i + 1], elements[i]       
        if not swapped:
            # exiting the function if we didn't make a single swap
            # meaning that the array is already sorted.
            return

bubblesort(PALABRA)

print(PALABRA)
```

**Resultado**

```
['avispa', 'caña', 'casa', 'manía', 'nadie', 'ñandú', 'ñanduti', 'oeste', 'oesteaa', 'peña', 'peñón', 'perezoso', 'retoño', 'retorno', 'volar', 'volátil', 'zanahoria']
```

Comment: Excelente solucion, muchaa gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Es una pregunta interesante, porque hasta lo que sé, los módulos built-in de python no ordenan cadenas ignorando estos caracteres, si no que las ordenan al final del listado.

Se me ocurre que se podrían reemplazar los caracteres acentuados por los "normales" y las ñ por otra cosa para hacer el ordenamiento de esa lista modificada y luego revertir los reemplazos.

```py
palabras = ['agua', 'mora', 'zapato', 'ámbar', 'ñandú', 'ímpetu', 'nota']

repl = {'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i', 'ó':'o', 'ú':'u', 'ñ':'nñ'}
tmpdic = {}
for pal in palabras:
    key = ''
    for letra in pal:
        if letra in repl:
            key += repl[letra]
        else:
            key += letra
    tmpdic[key] = pal
```

Hasta este punto, `tmpdic` tendrá lo siguiente:

```py
{'agua': 'agua', 'mora': 'mora', 'zapato': 'zapato', 'ambar': 'ámbar', 
'nñandu': 'ñandú', 'impetu': 'ímpetu', 'nota': 'nota'}
```

Ahora se puede ordenar los keys, con cualquier forma normal de ordenamiento, `sort()`, `sorted()`, método de burbuja, etc...

```py
sorted_keys = sorted(tmpdic) # <-- Aplicar el ordenamiento aquí

# Ahora se revierte reemplazando los keys por su respectivo valor:

res = [tmpdic[k] for k in sorted_keys]
print(res)
# ['agua', 'ámbar', 'ímpetu', 'mora', 'nota', 'ñandú', 'zapato']
```

Comment: Una mejor solución:  usa el parámetro `key` de la función `sort`. No sé si `sorted` también lo tiene. Puedes pasarle una función o un lambda. Por ejemplo: `lambda cadena: cadena.replace("ñ", "n")`. Los ordena en base al resultado de la función o lambda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la solución!

Answer (score 3):

Primero, ordenas alphabeticamente tu lista o lista de palabras o cadena... Entonces se *supone* que si usas la letra que quieres investigar, como parámetro la letra variante, convertido en una lista, `lista_de_palabras.index(letra_variante) = index[0:-1]` e index - la longitud de la palabra variante entonces puedes tener una especie de ordenamiento.

```
PALABRA = sorted(['retorno', 'peñón', 'ñandú', 'casa', 'zanahoria', 'volar', 'caña', 'perezoso', 'ñanduti', 'manía', 'retoño', 'avispa', 'volátil', 'peña', 'nadie', 'oeste'])

indice = -1
for i in range(len(PALABRAS)):
    if PALABRAS[i][0] == 'ñ': 
        indice = i
        break

PALABRA = PALABRA[indice:] + PALABRA[:indice]
```

El valor *unicode* de "*ñ*" es 241, lo que equivale a ser mayor a la "*z*" (122), supongo que es por la forma en que son definidos este tipo de caracteres en el lenguaje, entonces usando este método colocarías las palabras con la letra especificada de primero seguido de las otras en orden alfabético.

```
>>> ord('ñ')
241
>>> ord('z')
122
>>> 'ñ' > 'z'
True
>>> PALABRA
['ñanduti', 'ñandú', 'avispa', 'casa', 'caña', 'manía', 'nadie', 'oeste', 'perezoso', 'peña', 'peñón', 'retorno', 'retoño', 'volar', 'volátil', 'zanahoria']
```

ejemplo con otra letra diferente a la `ñ`

```
>>> # Ordenado a partir de la letra 'n'
>>> PALABRA
['nadie', 'oeste', 'perezoso', 'peña', 'peñón', 'retorno', 'retoño', 'volar', 'volátil', 'zanahoria', 'ñanduti', 'ñandú', 'avispa', 'casa', 'caña', 'manía']
```

Una forma para ordenarlas como el alfabeto español podría ser que ordenes la lista usando `sort()` entonces apartes las palabras de las palabras que no contienen la letra `n` y luegos ubiques el indice que cumpla con la condición de `PALABRA[indice][0] == 'n' or PALABRA[indice+1][0] > 'n'` y a partir de ahí concatenar las listas.

```
temp = []
PALABRA.sort()

while PALABRA[-1][0] == 'ñ':
    temp.append(PALABRA.pop())

for i in range(len(PALABRA)):
    if PALABRA[i][0] == 'n':
        index_i = i
        while index_i < len(PALABRA) and PALABRA[index_i][0] == 'n':
            index_i += 1
        if index_i >= len(PALABRA):
             PALABRA = PALABRA+temp
        else:
             PALABRA = PALABRA[:index_i] + temp + PALABRA[index_i+1:]
        break
    elif PALABRA[i][0] > 'n':
        if i == 0:
            PALABRA = temp + PALABRA
        else:
            PALABRA = PALABRA[i-1:] + temp + PALABRA[i:]
        break
```

esto para un test básico puede ordenarlo, pero puede tener errores, por ejemplo si el ultimo carácter contiene una letra 'n' o si no hay intervalos entre las palabras menor o igual a la letra 'o', etc...

```
>>> PALABRA
['avispa', 'casa', 'caña', 'manía', 'ñandú', 'ñanduti', 'oeste', 'perezoso', 'peña', 'peñón', 'retorno', 'retoño', 'volar', 'volátil', 'zanahoria']
```

Answer (score 3):

Como siempre tarde y con ayudita... de otros.

```
import unicodedata  

palabra = ["Retorno", "tete", "rie", "Peñón", "ñandú", "casa",
           "zanahoria","Zanahoria", "Volar", "volar", "caña", "perezoso",
           "ñanduti", "manía", "retoño", "avispa",
           "volátil", "peña", "nadie", "oeste"]
           
largo = len( palabra ) -1

desordenado = True
while desordenado:
    i = 0
    desordenado = False
    while i < largo:
        palabraA = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", palabra[ i ].lower() ).encode("ascii","ignore").decode("ascii") 
        palabraB = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", palabra[ i + 1 ].lower() ).encode("ascii","ignore").decode("ascii") 
        if palabraA > palabraB:
            desordenado = True
            aux = palabra[ i ]
            palabra[ i ], palabra[ i + 1 ] = palabra[ i + 1 ], palabra[ i ]
        i += 1
    largo -= 1

print( palabra )
```

Para empezar, apliqué el algoritmo de la burbuja, pero se puede aplicar cualquier otro.
La única cosa destacable de este código, es la linea...

```
palabraA = unicodedata.normalize( "NFKD", palabra[ i ].lower() ).encode( "ascii", "ignore" ).decode( "ascii" )
```

que se encarga de quitarle todos los "adornos" a las letras.
Para información más detallada ver [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

PD: horrible no poder usar funciones...

Comment: Buenisima solución, y en efecto es super complicado sin funciones.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya gustado, y si, yo soy medio "fan" de las funciones, códigos cortitos que hacen poco... reutilización a "full".

Answer (score 3):

```
           "zanahoria", "volar", "caña", "perezoso",
           "ñanduti", "manía", "retoño", "avispa",
           "volátil", "peña", "nadie", "oeste"]

print("Ordenamiento de palabras")

def ORDENONASCII(PAL):
    if "ñ" in PAL:
        PAL=PAL.replace("ñ","nñ")
    return (PAL)
def PALABRAS_ORDENADAS(PALABRA):
    for k in range (len(PALABRA)):
        for j in range (len(PALABRA)-1):
                if PALABRA[k]<PALABRA[j]:
                    PALABRA[k],PALABRA[j]=PALABRA[j],PALABRA[k]
    return (PALABRA)
def REPLACE_IN_PALABRAS_ORD (PALABRA_ORD):
    LISTA_ORDENADA = []
    for palabra in PALABRA_ORD:
        if "ñ" in palabra:
            palabra = palabra.replace("nñ", "ñ")
        LISTA_ORDENADA.append(palabra)
    return LISTA_ORDENADA


N=int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que desea ordenar:"))
PALABRA=[]
for i in range (N):
    PAL=input("Ingrese una palabra en minúsculas:")
    PAL= ORDENONASCII(PAL)
    PALABRA.append(PAL)
LISTA_ORIGINAL=REPLACE_IN_PALABRAS_ORD(PALABRA)
print("La lista original de palabras es:",LISTA_ORIGINAL)
PALABRA_ORD=PALABRAS_ORDENADAS(PALABRA)
LISTA_ORDENADA=REPLACE_IN_PALABRAS_ORD(PALABRA_ORD)
print("La lista ordenada de palabras es:",LISTA_ORDENADA)
```